# Xcode code autocompletion strange behaviour in function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, plugins, autocomplete

Code completion suddenly stopped working in my `viewDidLoad` function. However, strangely, autocomplete works properly in other functions. It turns out that autocomplete does not work after a lot of code in a particular function. The `viewDidLoad` function has around 100 lines of code. And autocomplete becomes extremely slow after this. Autocomplete works properly in other projects.

P.S- The following did not work- Deleting Derived Data, commands in terminal etc. I had installed FuzzyAutocomplete through the Alcatraz plug in, but I deleted Alcatraz soon after. I think the fuzzy autocomplete plug in has still not been uninstalled even though I deleted alcatraz by pasting this into terminal-

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin
```

I think there is some bug, and fuzzy autocomplete has blocked the Xcode code completion. All of this did not help. What can I do? Please help.

Comment: It's a common situation. Don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So well, I finally figured this out. I reinstalled Xcode on my laptop, and the problem didn't seem to go away. So I got to know that there was something wrong with my code. Xcode might have probably got stuck while processing that bit of code. So I slowly kept on commenting out one line after the other while checking whether code completion had started to work. I narrowed this down to one code block in my `viewDidLoad()` function which involved quite a lot of calculation. When I narrowed it down to just this much, Xcode suddenly gave me an **error**- `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time. Consider breaking up the expression in distinct sub-expressions`. That line involved a long calculation of addition and subtraction which made Xcode get stuck on it which is why code completion could not find enough memory to run smoothly in that particular function, and Xcode kept on indexing again and again. For some reason, the previously installed copy of Xcode did not give me this error. Thankfully, this copy did. So the problem was sorted.

P.S- I was using Xcode 7.1 which was the latest version.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning which versions of Xcode you were using.